# How to install Microsoft Windows Terminal in Windows 10 version 1909

Tags: windows, powershell, chocolatey, windows-terminal

**[Note]** *this is a historic problem that is specific to Windows 10 version 1909, which does not satisfy the Windows Terminal requirement by then. It would no longer be a problem for most nowadays systems.*

Alright, this should be a fairly simple question, but failing every possibilities, I'm afraid that it is becoming a loaded one, just **to get [Microsoft Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:regionofsystemrequirementstab) installed**.

The [Microsoft Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:regionofsystemrequirementstab)

> is a new, modern, fast, efficient, powerful, and productive terminal application for users of command-line tools and shells like Command Prompt, PowerShell, and WSL. Its main features include multiple tabs, Unicode and UTF-8 character support, a GPU accelerated text rendering engine, and custom themes, styles, and configurations.

It is an open source project available at https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

- Trying to install from https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases, I'll get:
  [image]
- Trying to install from [Microsoft Windows Terminal Shop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:regionofsystemrequirementstab), I'll get (and the result would be the same if I do search from Microsoft Shop and click on it):

[image]

- Trying to install with `choco install microsoft-windows-terminal`, I'll get:

  ```
    ERROR: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF3, Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.

    Windows cannot install package Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_0.11.1121.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe because this package depends on a framework that could not be found. Provide the framework "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00" published by "CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US", with neutral or x64 processor architecture and minimum version 14.0.27810.0, along with this package to install. The frameworks with name "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00" currently installed are: {Microsoft.VCLibs.140
    Windows cannot install package Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_0.11.1121.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe because this package depends on a framework that could not be found. Provide the framework "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00" published by "CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US", with neutral or x64 processor architecture and minimum version 14.0.27810.0, along with this package to install. The frameworks with name "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00" currently installed are: {Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.26706.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.26706.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe}
  ```

Although I've exhausted all my searches and am sure that I have the dependent thing:

```
PS > Get-AppxPackage -allusers *Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00* | Select Name, PackageFullName

Name                               PackageFullName
----                               ---------------
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop_14.0.26905.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00            Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.26706.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00            Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.26706.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop_14.0.27810.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

So, once again, simple question, how to get Microsoft Windows Terminal installed? thx.

Comment: What version of windows 10 do you have?

Comment: Windows 10 version 1909 v10.0.18363.0 now, @js2010, and now I'm good. The differences between now and then is that, I was trying to update my Windows system myself, while this time it is push updated by our company's IT team. thx everyone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Installing it straight from the Microsoft Store didn't work for me either.  In Windows 10 1909, I did (it's an msix).  Note that the appx commands are *gone* in powershell 7.1.

```
Add-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_0.11.1191.0_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle
```

and it installed ok.

```
get-appxpackage microsoft.windowsterminal


Name              : Microsoft.WindowsTerminal
Publisher         : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture      : X64
ResourceId        :
Version           : 0.11.1191.0
PackageFullName   : Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_0.11.1191.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
InstallLocation   : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_0.11.1191.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsFramework       : False
PackageFamilyName : Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe
PublisherId       : 8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsResourcePackage : False
IsBundle          : False
IsDevelopmentMode : False
NonRemovable      : False
Dependencies      : {Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.27810.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                    Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop_14.0.27810.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe}
IsPartiallyStaged : False
SignatureKind     : Store
Status            : Ok
```

Alt-down arrow-settings to get the default settings json.

Comment: `'Add-AppxPackage' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @JeremyThille Yep, the *-appxpackage commands are gone in powershell 7.1.

Comment: I am trying to install an application that I developed. My powerShell that executes this command (Add-AppxPackage) runs with the system user. When installing the package, there are also dependencies (DependencyPath). When it runs, there is an error that the system user does not have permission to perform the operation. Does anyone know how to explain to me why the system would not have this permission? Developer mode is enabled on the machine

Answer (score 1):

I recommend on using choco [ it's short of similar to apt-get on linux :( but not that powerful ]. It contains most of the packages. click here [CHOCO](https://chocolatey.org/install) to install choco and search for windows terminal package, Just run a single command in powershell[ADMIN PRIVILEGED] and you are all set to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should install this dependence: Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00. You can get it only from VLSC ISO image called "SW_DVD9_NTRL_Win_10_1903_32_64_ARM64_MultiLang_App_Update_X22-01657.ISO" (if your Windows 10 version is 1903/1909). Google it. The site with alive link will be in the top of search. Unfortunately these kind of packages is distributed only within VLSC.

Comment: Thanks, but if you check my OP again, you'd realized that I've already have ***four*** versions of Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00 installed already.

Comment: May be your should uninstall these (all?) UWP apps and install from ISO I mentioned within PowerShell? Because it's very odd situation. Did you try wsreset.exe?

Comment: hmm... since no direct url and no specific version has been provided, I'm not sure if this fifth dll from the fifth tip can make any difference. Moreover, I found from [here](https://files.rg-adguard.net/file/4e450aab-2bfc-b42c-4e42-3acd8b0d08a3) that the ISO is of 4.227 GB in size. That's a bit too dramatic for a small tool like Windows Terminal. I have to say I'm really really frustrated that such a simple tool needs me jumping through firing hoops backwards, and after I've done all, it is still not working. Sorry not to venting about you farag, but about the overall situation.

Comment: Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -ErrorAction Ignore | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers  -ErrorAction Ignore -Verbose. It will delete all UWP apps from all accounts. Then reinstall from here: https://ulozto.net/file/juZHCxmGalIy/amd64fre-rar. You can install only two apps: DesktopAppInstaller and all related with Microsoft Store. Then install all others appx by clicking on them (they will become installers). May be tommorrow I'll download thei archive by myselft to update my repo: https://github.com/farag2/Utilities/tree/master/diag/appx

Comment: Any chance you guys can extract `api-ms-win-core-wow-64-l1-1-1.dll` as it only seem available from higher versions (and required by WT).